# typo3 8.7.x tx_news 7.0.5 overwrite default meta tag title with news title

Tags: typo3, meta-tags, typo3-8.x, tx-news

I'm using `tx_news` 7.0.5 in `typo3` 8.7.19 and have troubles with the meta tag title on detail page.

All news get the same title "detail" (name of detail page) and will not get the page title which is the title of the news.

If I edit the `opengraph` template I can add

```
<n:metaTag name="title" content="{newsItem.title}" />
```

But with this i get the meta title twice. So that's a bad idea.
Any suggestions how to solve the issue with getting the right meta title in detail page of `tx_news`?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to disable your default `title`-generation.

somewhere for each page you have a configuration like

```
page.meta.title.field = title
```

this needs to be disabled for pages where you show a news.

the news-detail-pages normaly can be identified by a get-parameter for the news uid

```
[globalVar = GP:tx_news_pi1|news > 0]
    page.meta.title.field = title
[global]
```

or you have a list of pages where the news details are displayed:

```
[page|uid = 123,234,32]
    page.meta.title.field = title
[global]
```

**Be careful** if the detail-page also is a list page. this condition does not differ.